# Leaf too long? Honey mango

Tags: trees, seedlings, container-gardening, tropical, mango

The seedling is not even 3 inches tall and has a leaf bigger than itself. This is a polyembryonic honey mango seed. It gets 1 hour of sunlight daily and the pot has no drainage holes. I also am probably overwatering it. I water it once a day.[image]

Comment: Good question; if could include length of the leaf, overall height, current watering amount, current nutrient type, amount & frequency, size of container, hours of diffuse light per day, age of the seedling, average daytime temperature, and average night time temperature, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help] to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be concerned about the size of that one leaf, it looks healthy, but it is a concern that you have it in a pot without drainage holes. Since you mention it yourself, you probably already know it shouldn't be in something that doesn't have drainage holes, so I'd recommend you move it into a pot with holes; the difficulty is deciding when to do that so as not to cause damage to fragile new roots. You may need to wait until it grows on a bit more, unless it starts to show problems related with poor drainage.

Information here about growing mango from seed - you will need to scroll down a fair way to get past the 'how to germinate' section https://empressofdirt.net/grow-mango-seed/

Comment: I just put it in a pot with drainage holes, I broke the the tip of the longest root but it was just the very very tip but it was still hanging on by a thread.

Comment: fingers crossed then!